# How to handle mouse moving

Tags: qt, mousemove

I need to handle mouse moving.

I overrided function

```
void MouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
```

And it works only when mouse button is pressed.

Comment: Did your read the documentation about QWidget::mouseMoveEvent() at all? It is clearly written there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From documentation: "If mouse tracking is switched off, mouse move events only occur if a mouse button is pressed while the mouse is being moved. If mouse tracking is switched on, mouse move events occur even if no mouse button is pressed."

Read about setMouseTracking().